# Building a "Filter Proxy" in Node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch Server which I would like to query, but before showing the result to the User I want to filter the results (looking up the rights for the User in a Database etc.)

So I thought I write a proxy Server which recieves JSON POST Search request and redirect this to the Elasticsearch Server. The response with the results now be sent to the "filter server". This Server looks the recieved json-data up in a Database and removes the results which the User isn't allowed to see. This filtered content should be presented to the user.

Ok - this is what i've done:

```
var proxy = http.createServer(function (req, res){
  if(req.method == 'OPTIONS'){
   res.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type':   'application/json; charset=UTF-8'});
   res.end();
 }

if(req.method == 'POST'){

  var searchOptions = {
    host: '10.0.10.1',
    port: 9200,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/ltg_5096/_search'
  }

    var searchRequest = http.request(searchOptions, function(searchResponse){

    // this is the Request to the Elasticsearch Server...

    var filterOptions = {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8080,
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }

    var filterRequest = http.request(filterOptions, function(filterResponse){
      // ?! This should be the request to the filter Server
    })

    searchResponse.pipe(res)
    res.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'})
  })
  req.pipe(searchRequest)
 }
})

proxy.listen(9000)
```

This is the proxy Server but without the part where the results are filtered by the filtering instance. I tried lots of things, but couldn't get it to work as I want it to. I hope somebody can help me with this!

Comment: What is a filter server? I think you need to provide more detail. I don't see why you can't just remove entry inside of nodejs.

Comment: the filter server removes entries from the search result - the server queries an informix database and checks if the user is allowed to see the search results. This can't be done (without much hassle) with node. Thats why I want to use node just for "routing" the different requests

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried? It appears that the filter server is REST based, so I'd assume the first step is to write the contents to the filterRequest. You haven't provided much detail or really a question that can be answered. If you provide more information about this "filter server" or ask a definite question I can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you need:

https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/node.es

This is a simple but useful elasticsearch proxy, built on node.js, the proxy allow to intercept and modify requests and responses, by defining two functions:

```
var preRequest = function(request) {};
var postRequest = function(request, response, responseData){};
var proxyServer = proxyFactory.getProxy(preRequest, postRequest);
proxyServer.start();
```

Take a look to this example:

https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/node.es/blob/master/proxy/proxy-example.js